# CodenameOne stopped working after build

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, codenameone

I have an odd issue with codenameone, and I'm not even sure what went wrong. I've tried to "send windows phone build", and don't think I have changed anything else since then. However, after I did so the simulator wouldn't launch and kept saying my imports were wrong. They weren't, the suggested solution was importing once that were already in.

The errors I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor.main(Executor.java:45)
... 5 more
```

All the classes he can't find are actually in my solution, I already tried re-adding them to the build path. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is odd.

First check that you indeed still have the package `com.mycompany.myapp` where you have the public class `MyApplication`. Do a clean build of the project and see if this class makes it into the jar file under the dist folder.

Comment: I have copied all classes to a newly created CN1 project, it runs fine now. The other one, exactly the same code, keeps giving that error. The package still exists :)

Comment: Is the class still there, is it still public with a default constructor?