# Codename One simulator stopped working after Android build

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

I'm having an issue very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729090/codenameone-stopped-working-after-build). I have a Codename One project in Eclipse that was working in the simulator, but after a successful Android build, the simulator suddenly no longer works. It throws all these errors:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory.createImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:69)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.init(Display.java:566)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1.run(Executor.java:112)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1004)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:100)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:50)
    ... 17 more
```

I am using the latest version of Eclipse running on Ubuntu. Could this be specific to the OS or IDE? It throws no errors when building and says "Build successful", so the problem seems to be isolated to the simulator itself. There may be something simple I am missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: Duplicate: [Running app in IDE stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43196710/running-app-in-ide-stops-working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your project is using a non-oracle JRE, which doesn't include JavaFX.  You'll need to set the JRE/JDK that the project runs in to an Oracle JDK.